# Openshift Spring MVC Tomcat application's deployed path returns 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7, openshift

I am running a Tomcat7 application using Spring MVC on OpenShift under the domain: [financial-datasite.rhcloud.com](http://financial-datasite.rhcloud.com). I run and test the application locally using a Tomcat server and later push it to the remote repository. Currently, there's only a HomePage and a button underneath redirecting to a different page. When testing locally, both pages display contents as expected. However, when deployed to the remote server, only the HomePage is displayed, and on clicking the button, I get an HTTP 404 error. I have come across various similar questions here, but none of them have helped so far. I have played around configuring the web.xml, pom.xml, servlet-context.xml, and the controller files. However, none of those have helped. I have also been checking the [tail files and logs](http://pastebin.com/2sgZ3d8e) to monitor what's happening, which suggests that the remote server is accessing some 'printWelcome' method (which doesn't even exist in my project) in the controller class for the second page:

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/Sectors],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.spring.mvc.SectorController.printWelcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
```

Here is my [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaykI.jpg). In my localhost, the default page is run as `localhost:8181/mvc/` and the second page is run as `http://localhost:8181/mvc/Sectors`. Similarly, post deployment, the home page is run as http://financial-datasite.rhcloud.com and the second page executed as http://financial-datasite.rhcloud.com/Sectors, which throws a 404 error for /WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp, which, again, doesn't even exist in my project directory. Another thing I observed in the log files are that the code is likely not hitting the SectorController class as I have coded for print commands to be logged, which aren't really getting logged into the console when the page is requested from the deployed site. I am quite unsure about which files are being run on the remote server and if there are any configuration issues that I am unaware of. Following are my web.xml, pom.xml, servlet-context.xml, Sectors.jsp, Google-Maps.js from where I've called the new page to load), and SectorController.java (which is the controller file for the second page). Apologies for a lengthy question, please let me know if you require any more information. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

  <display-name>Financial Data Site</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>financial</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>financial</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvc</artifactId>
    <name>SpringMVC</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>

        <!-- Newly Added from here -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <!-- Till here -->

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tag Library -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
          <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.2</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be 
                used when invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization 
                your app will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 
                'deployments' folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
            <finalName>financial</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapp</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.mvc" />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**Sectors.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sectors</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Message</h1>
    <c:if test="${not empty Sectors}">

        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="_SectorNames" items="${Sectors}">
                <li>${_SectorNames}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>

    </c:if>
</body>

</html>
```

**Google-Maps.js**: following snippet only contains the function used to create a div section on the map and to call a new page on a new window

```
function HomeControl(controlDiv, map)
{
      // Set CSS for the control border.
      var _ControlUI = document.createElement('div');
      _ControlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
      _ControlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
      _ControlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
      _ControlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
      _ControlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      _ControlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
      _ControlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
      _ControlUI.title = 'Click to filter by Sectors';
      controlDiv.appendChild(_ControlUI);

      // Set CSS for the control interior.
      var _ControlText = document.createElement('div');
      _ControlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
      _ControlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
      _ControlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
      _ControlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
      _ControlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
      _ControlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
      _ControlText.innerHTML = '<strong>View by Sectors</strong>';
      _ControlUI.appendChild(_ControlText);

      // Setup the click event listeners, also calls Sectors page on a new window
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(_ControlUI, 'click', function() {
          //add code here to redirect to Sectors page
          var _Window = window.open('/mvc/Sectors', '__blank');
          _Window.focus();
      });
}
```

**SectorController.java**

```
    package com.spring.mvc;

    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import com.spring.dao.impl.SectorDAOImpl;
    import com.spring.model.Sector;

    @Controller
    public class SectorController {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SectorController.class);

        @RequestMapping(value = "/Sectors", method = {RequestMethod.HEAD, RequestMethod.GET})
        public ModelAndView DisplaySectors(Locale locale, Model model) {

            logger.info("Welcome home! You are in: {}.", locale);

            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

            String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

            model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

            SectorDAOImpl _SectorDAOImpl = new SectorDAOImpl();
            List<Sector> _Sectors = _SectorDAOImpl.GetByID();       
            List<String> _SectorNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            for( Sector sector : _Sectors) {
                _SectorNames.add(sector.getSectorName());
            }

            ModelAndView _ModelAndView = new ModelAndView("Sectors");
            _ModelAndView.addObject("Sectors", _SectorNames);

            return _ModelAndView;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post also the code where the button fires the request to the page please? Also can you post an image with your project structure please

Comment: Posted the JavaScript code that requests the new page. I've also posted a link to an image of the project structure on the question above, here's the link for reference: http://imgur.com/WhOuzJB. Thanks.

Comment: In this line:  var _Window = window.open('/mvc/Sectors', '__blank'); Why are you prefixing with "/mvc/"? Is that your project name?

Comment: @Jessai: That is because the home page on localhost by default loads localhost:8181/mvc/, and therefore requires /mvc/ to be prefixed before directing to any other page, else it throws a 404 error again. I have however tried on the remote server without the /mvc/ prefix, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the WAR you are pushing to openshift is called ROOT.war?

Comment: I have mentioned ROOT as the <warName> in my 'pom.xml' (as it can be seen in the code snipped above), but I am not quite sure how to determine if the WAR being pushed to OpenShift is called ROOT.war? Is there a way to find out the same? Thanks.

Comment: When you export your WAR just name it as ROOT.war. :)

Comment: Sorry to be a bit novice on this one, but I am not quite sure where or how one exports a WAR file. Like I can't see any file named WAR in particular in my project. Also, what does a WAR file contain? I've been doing some research on this one, but still quite clueless to be honest. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A .war file is a Java Web Application file, similar to a .zip file. In your IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans or similar) you can EXPORT your web application as a war file. Now I'm not sure how are you pushing your app to openshift :P or are you using git with openshift?

Comment: Oh right, okay! Well I use an OpenShift plugin within Eclipse which lets me perform a one click push to the remote repository, and yes it uses Git to do so. Are you then suggesting that I export my whole Eclipse project as a WAR file and somehow push the WAR file to OpenShift?

Comment: When I was developing a spring app in openshift, I had issues with the URL because of the name of the war file. Check this URL in the section named Deploying WAR files using Git. https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740-How-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-WAR-and-EAR-files-onto-your-OpenShift-gear-using-the-java-cartridges

Answer (score 4):

1. As Jessai noted in a comment,

   ```
   var _Window = window.open('/mvc/Sectors', '__blank');
   ```

   Do not use your project name explicitly! There are a ways to get your context name, such as request.getContextPath() method of HttpServletRequest.

   In this case with a hard-coded URL string I think that you can use relative URL, just 'Sectors' or './Sectors'.

   References:

   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
   - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-open
2. '__blank' :  you meant '_blank' ?
3. By the way:

   You are deploying on Tomcat 7, so you can declare adherence to Servlet 3.0 specification instead of 2.5 in your `web.xml` file.

   See the following to disable components scanning at startup:
   https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Configure_your_web_application
4. On

   ```
   INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/Sectors],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.spring.mvc.SectorController.printWelcome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
   ```

   If your class file does not match your source code, it means that your code has not been compiled. Delete your compiled classes (e.g. use `mvn clean`) and try again.

   If you are curious, you can unpack your war file with any ZIP archiver application and look what is actually there.
5. Do you or our company own the domain name of http://spring.com web site? If not, DO NOT use package name `com.spring` and do not use `<groupId>com.spring</groupId>`. Those names do not belong to you. They are someone else's property.
6. On

   ```
   <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
   ```

   If you are using 3.x, why not the current 3.2.12.RELEASE in 3.x series, or better the last 4.1.6.RELEASE?  Spring Framework 3.1.x has reached end of life and is no more supported.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've actually tried all the above steps you've recommended, except the last one on the 4th point (unpack WAR and look what is actually there). If you're talking about unpacking the WAR file I've uploaded myself, it has all the expected code I have on my client machine. Yet when deployed, the path returns 404 error.

Comment: Enable AccessLogValve in your server configuration to create access log file for your requests so that you see what URLs your client (browser) is actually requesting. In Tomcat you can enable an access log globally for your Host in conf/server.xml file. (I do not know whether that is true for "jbossews" that you are using. It is a different software).